# Custom iterator on a namedtuple

Tags: python

Is there a pythonic way to have a custom iterator on a namedtuple?

A custom iterator appears to require an index attribute. Normally a namedtuple has a "`__slots__ = ()`" declaration, which avoids the overhead of a dynamic dict and reduces latency in attribute lookup. However, this breaks the iterator (`AttributeError: 'Path' object has no attribute '_iidx'`). Adding `_iidx` to the slots results in `nonempty __slots__ not supported`

Context: I will be working with a large number of Bezier splines. Each spline consists of a list of 'knot' points, and list of pairs of control points. By commenting out the `__slots__ = ()` declaration, my code works. But, at the cost of having a per-instance dynamic dict. The overhead from the dict in attribute lookup is probably negligible compared to everything else, but it doesn't seem pythonic.

```
class Path(namedtuple('Path', "knots ctrl_pts")):
#    __slots__ = ()

    @property
    def SVG(self):
        s = 'M %s' % self.knots[0].bare
        for cps, k in self:
            s += ' C %s %s' % (cps.bare, k.bare)
        return s

    def __iter__(self):
        self._iidx = 0
        return self

    def __next__(self):
        if self._iidx == len(self.ctrl_pts):
            raise StopIteration
        i = self._iidx
        self._iidx += 1
        return (self.ctrl_pts[i], self.knots[i+1])
```

The SVG method uses the iterator to make SVG formating trivial. This:

```
print('<path d="%s" stroke="black" stroke-width="1" fill="blue" />'
       % path.SVG)
```

Results in:

```
<path d="M 318.9 179.4 C 279.1 177.6 199.2 270.3 222.4 298.1 C 245.5
326.0 371.6 289.1 420.4 297.0 C 469.2 304.9 440.6 357.6 399.6 352.4
C 388.5 350.9 389.7 345.0 400.4 347.6 C 440.1 357.4 469.4 309.2 419.6
303.0 C 369.8 296.7 240.9 332.5 217.6 301.9 C 194.4 271.2 276.9 174.1
319.1 174.6 C 330.3 174.7 329.9 179.9 318.9 179.4" stroke="black"
stroke-width="1" fill="blue" />
```

But it also is trivial to use in the `on_draw(self, wid, cr):` of a Gtk.DrawingArea:

```
        path = self.coords.outline_path 
        cr.set_source_rgb(*LT_BLUE)
        cr.move_to(*path.knots[0])
        for (c,k) in path:
            cr.curve_to(*c.P1, *c.P2, *k)
        cr.fill_preserve()
        cr.set_source_rgb(*BLACK)
        cr.stroke()
```

Note: the 'knots' is a `List[Point]` and 'ctrl_pts' is a `List[ControlPoints]`:

```
class Point(namedtuple('Point', "x y")):
    __slots__ = ()
    """<bunch of stuff not shown>"""
    @property
    def bare(self):
        return '%.1f %.1f' % (self.x, self.y)

class ControlPoints(namedtuple('ControlPoints', "P1 P2")):
    __slots__ = ()
    @property
    def bare(self):
        return '%s %s' % (self.P1.bare, self.P2.bare)
```

I am very new to python and I am certain this can be done in a more pythonic way.

Comment: Why don't you just not use `__slots__`?

Comment: Can't use non-empty `__slots__` on a namedtuple. It results in `nonempty __slots__ not supported`

Comment: I said why don't you just *not* use `__slots__`.  Why not just accept the `__dict__`?

Comment: Sorry for my misunderstanding. Yes, that is exactly what I am currently doing by commenting out the `__slots__` declaration. As I mention, the extra overhead of a dynamic dict does make every attribute lookup a little slower, but it probably doesn't compare to the rest of the actions. Mostly, it just felt non-pythonic to have a namedtuple with the overhead of a dict, and I was hoping for better.

Answer (score 1):

Rather than implementing the iterator protocol manually, make `__iter__` a generator for the values you want.  The generator object implements the iterator protocol for you.

```
class Path(namedtuple('Path', "knots ctrl_pts")):

    @property
    def SVG(self):
        s = 'M %s' % self.knots[0].bare
        for cps, k in self:
            s += ' C %s %s' % (cps.bare, k.bare)
        return s

    def __iter__(self):
        for t in zip(self.ctrl_pts, self.knots[1:]):
            yield t
```

If you only expect `__iter__` to be used as part of `SVG`, you really don't need it, and can use something like this:

```
class Path(namedtuple('Path', "knots ctrl_pts")):

    @property
    def SVG(self):
        return 'M %s%s' % (self.knots[0].bare, 
                           ''.join([' C %s %s' % (cps.bare, k.bare)
                                    for cps, k in zip(self.ctrl_pts, self.knots[1:])]))
```

Answer (score 1):

To make your code work as is, add `_iidx` to the attribute list in the call to namedtuple().

Note that inheriting from a namedtuple class makes further sub-classing less useful because inheritors can not add new attributes. This may or may not matter in your application. As an alternative you can inherit from `object` and call out the attribute names in `__slots__`. This will preserve much of the performance benefits of inheriting from a namedtuple, and make it so that inheritors can define new attributes in their `__slots__`.

Changes below include:

1. `__iter__` now returns a generator that manages looping for you so you don't need `_iidx` anymore. Check out [itertools](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html) for interesting ways of creating iterators. Defining `__next__` is often more work than is necessary.
2. The svg property now accumulates strings in a list and then joins them. This is usually faster than the increment operator on str.
3. The last bit is changing the svg property to lowercase. This is purely style but it is more in line with the core language's [style guide](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/).

.

```
from itertools import izip    # python 2 only

class Path(namedtuple('Path', "knots ctrl_pts")):
    __slots__ = ()

    @property
    def svg(self):    # attribute names are usually lower case
        # accumulating strings with += is slow
        # use a list insted
        s = ['M %s' % self.knots[0].bare]
        for cps, k in self:
            s.append('C %s %s' % (cps.bare, k.bare))
        return ' '.join(s)

    def __iter__(self):
        # python 3
        return zip(self.ctrl_pts, self.knots[1:])

        # python 2
        return izip(self.ctrl_pts, self.knots[1:])
```

Comment: Unfortunately, for a namedtuple `Field names cannot start with an underscore: '_iidx'`. If I drop the underscore, __new__ fails.

Comment: I love the zip solution. Works great!! Please ignore the earlier comment. It was sent when I tried to add a <cr> and I was too slow editing it.